# Show Typescript command line options when building in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, typescript

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the VS 2015 Typescript project, and the differences between all the build options. When I read questions/answers on SO, they are usually referring to command line options, and I don't always know how they translate to the Typescript Build options in the VS 2015 UI.

Is there a window somewhere (or extension?) that shows the actual command line that visual studio runs when you select the various project Typescript Build options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio compiles TypeScript via `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`, that pass a path to options file to tsc.exe, e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe"  @"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp12bc368455ec43d08c6a17ac865eb778.rsp"
```

content of `.rsp` file:

```
--sourcemap --target ES6 --noEmitOnError --locale en-US "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\app.ts" ......
```

Unfortunately it is a temporary file, so it's hard to get options from it.

You can open `.csproj` file in text editor, find MSBuild options and get command-line equivalents:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Setting-Compiler-Options-in-MSBuild-projects

**Update:** You can enable verbose build output in Tools -> Options:
[image]